# Reference Number won't increment from Factory? - Using singleton Logger cannot reference Ref Number

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, logging, factory

Bit of a complicated question, I apologize if it is something stupid that I've missed. I've tried many solutions and solved it in a way but now the Reference Number within Customer will not increment on the .csv file?

This is the initial reference number being held to be used by the factory...

```
abstract class ReferenceNo
{
    static protected int _refNo;

    static public int ReferenceNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _refNo;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the factory which SHOULD increment the reference number...

```
class ReferenceNoFactory
{
    static private int lastbookingrefno = 0; // Last used booking reference number.
    static private int lastcustomerrefno = 0; // Last used customer reference number.

    static public ReferenceNo FactoryMethod(string type)
    {
        if (type == "Booking")
        {
            lastbookingrefno++; // Create new booking reference number.
            return new Booking(lastbookingrefno);

        }
        else if (type == "Customer")
        {
            lastcustomerrefno++; // Create a new customer reference number.
            return new Customer(lastcustomerrefno);
        }
        else
            return null; // Default, only a booking or customer reference number can be created.
                         // Nothing else should be returned, or null.
    }

}
```

This is the first part of the Customer class which gets the reference number and uses a logger instance to save it to the .csv file...

```
class Customer : ReferenceNo
{
    static private string FirstName;
    static private string LastName;
    static private string Address;

    public Customer(int refNo)
    {
        ReferenceNo._refNo = refNo;
    }

    static public void LogFile()
    {
        ReferenceNoFactory.FactoryMethod("Customer");

        CustomerLogger firstlogger = CustomerLogger.Instance;
        firstlogger.log(Customer.ReferenceNumber, Customer.firstname, Customer.lastname, Customer.address);
    }
```

And this is the logger which holds the filepath etc...

```
private static CustomerLogger instance;

    private CustomerLogger() {}

    public static CustomerLogger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if ( instance == null)
            {
                instance = new CustomerLogger();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void log(int custnum, string firstname, string lastname, string address)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("F:\\Software Dev 2\\Coursework 2\\Mia-CourseWork2\\Customers.csv", "CustRefNum," + custnum + ",FirstName, " + firstname + ",LastName," + lastname + ",Address," + address + "\n");
    }
```

The Reference number stays 1?...
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble replicating your problem, I ran your example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Customer.LogFile();
    Customer.LogFile();
}
```

I modified the logger to be simply:

```
public void log(int custnum, string firstname, string lastname, string address)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Customer.ReferenceNumber);
}
```

I get the following output:

> 1
>
> 2

I would suggest that you take a more conventional approach to your custom class and simply have non-static properties. If you want to store the last booking reference and the last customer reference I suggest you do use a property on the ReferenceNoFactory.

Comment: Understandably you're using the method twice, although it should increment with only using it once repeatedly? It's a holiday booking program so the data should be stored on the same .csv file with only the reference incrementing...?

Comment: @Mia.B can you add a usage example to your question so I can see what you mean?

Comment: sorry yeah it kinda works, it increments if i create 2 customers in the same program run-time. I think i just need some sort of validation for the program to see if the reference number is already in the file if that makes sense?

Comment: You probably don't want to be reading the file to do that. Simply add a method called IsCustomerCreated(int customRefNo) to the factory.

Comment: You are storing an incremental customerRefNo in the factory. You may need to get this value the first time you construct the class (but once once on start up). After that you can just use the factory value. However I'm not sure a log file is the place you really want to be storing this information. Shouldn't all your customer data be in a database?

Comment: It is for a University project , our profiles aren't allowed to connect to our database so we need to serialize. I dont fully understand how to use this factory value?/

Comment: You could make the class ReferenceNoFactory static (at the moment you are not declaring it as static above) and this might help you. Either way if you need to load up a starting Booking and Custom Ref Nos from somewhere, be it a log file or somewhere else.